# Optical theorem for the given diagram

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, unitarity

Assume we have the abelian gauge theory with single fermion. Suppose the following diagram: [image]

Here the initial "photon" $\gamma$ is in the same state as the final one, so this is the diagram of self-energy. I want to check whether the optical theorem holds for it.

The optical theorem for the total amplitude reads
$$
\tag 1 2\text{Im}M_{\gamma \to \gamma}= (2\pi)^{4}\sum_{n}|M_{\gamma \to n}|^{2}\delta (p_{n} - p_{\gamma}) \simeq \Gamma_{\gamma}
$$

The question: have I also take into account the diagram [image]
which is also 6th order of perturbation theory?

**An edit**

It seems that the formal answer is indeed yes. Really, the rhs of $(1)$ contains the half of the squared diagram, and the diagram above is needed in the lhs.

Comment: Could you explain a little more how you arrived at your conclusion in the edit you made?Is it the case that any  corrections we make to the diagram for $\gamma \rightarrow \gamma$ can be seen on the rhs of the optical theorem to originate from terms appearing in the $n$. So the meshing together of the diagram for $M_{\gamma \rightarrow n}$ and its conjugate may result in diagrams that are not $1\text{PI}$ etc and thus should be included on the lhs?

Comment: @CAF : it seems so. However, it is possible that there exists come general theorem providing some simplifications in treating these loop corrections.

Comment: Ok thanks - I just wondered 1) Isn't the optical theorem only helpful for finding the imaginary part of the TOTAL amplitude $M_{\gamma \rightarrow \gamma}$. So it cannot be used to find the imaginary part of a SINGLE diagram (unless of course there was only one diagram at a certain order) 2) Would you agree that the top most diagram in your post just evaluates to zero by virtue of Furry's theorem?

Comment: @CAF : 1) Of course; it collects the poles coming from all possible intermediate states. But in my case, I can drop the bottom diagram (and, of course, corresponding diagrams on the right hand side) since I know that they satisfy the optical theorem. 2)  Why has it to be zero due to Furry theorem?

Comment: I see. I've only just come across Furry's theorem in some reading but I thought since the fermion loops are connected to an odd number of photons , the amplitude had to be zero? E.g if I label your diagram as $A$ and reverse the loop momenta in one of the fermion loops this gives a diagram $B$ with a net minus sign $((-1)^3 = -1)$ in its amplitude relative to that for  $A$ so they cancel pairwise?

Comment: @CAF : this is true if the triangle diagram is $VVV$ (with $V$ denoting the vector-like gauge vertices). If, however, I assumed the chiral vertex $A$, then the $VVA$, $AAA$ diagrams are non-zero.

Comment: I see. Isn't the triangle diagrams in your diagram of the form $VVV$? (for each vertex we attach a term of the form $\bar u \gamma^{\mu} u$ which is a lorentz vector? ) Thanks!

Comment: @CAF : it may be arbitrary, as I didn't specialize the theory. However, I looked for violation of the unitarity by the abelian gauge anomaly, which is coded in the triangle diagrams, and hence I'm interested in the case of $VVA$ or $AAA$ diagrams.

Comment: Ok thanks!  could you provide a reference so I could see what you mean by the abelian gauge anomaly?

Comment: @CAF : suppose the abelian gauge theory with single fermion $\psi$ and axial-like gauge field $A_{\mu}$. The lagrangian is
$$
L = \bar{\psi}i\gamma^{\mu}(\partial_{\mu} -  i\gamma_{5}A_{\mu})\psi
$$
Naively (classically), this theory the axial current conservation law:
$$
\tag 1 \partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}_{5} = 0,
$$
where
$$
 J^{\mu}_{5} = \bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma_{5}\psi
$$
However, this is not true when we take into account quantum effects. This is convenient to do by using the quantum effective action $\Gamma[A]$, which includes all quantum loops corrections.

Comment: @CAF: The current vacuum expectation value $\langle J^{\mu}_{5}\rangle$ in the presence of the gauge field $A_{\mu}$ is
$$
\tag 2 \langle J^{\mu}_{5}(x)\rangle_{A} = \frac{\delta \Gamma[A]}{\delta A_{\mu}(x)},
$$
where $\frac{\delta}{\delta A_{\mu}(x)}$ is the variational derivative with respect to $A_{\mu}(x)$.

Comment: @CAF : Let's formally expand $(2)$ in the series over $A_{\mu}(x)$:
$$
\langle J^{\mu}_{5}(x)\rangle_{A} = \frac{\delta \Gamma[A]}{\delta A_{\mu}(x)}\bigg|_{A = 0} + 1/2\int d^{4}y \frac{\delta^{2}\Gamma[A]}{\delta A_{\mu}(x)\delta A_{\nu}(y)}\bigg|_{A = 0}A_{\nu}(y) + 
$$
$$
+1/3! \int d^{4}yd^{4}z\frac{\delta^{3}\Gamma[A]}{\delta A_{\mu}(x)\delta A_{\nu}(y)\delta A_{\rho}(z)}\bigg|_{A = 0}A_{\nu}(y)A_{\rho}(z)+...
$$

Comment: @CAF : The quantity 
$$
\Gamma^{(n)}_{\mu_{1}...\mu_{n}}(x_{1},...,x_{n}) \equiv \frac{1}{n!}\frac{\delta^{n} \Gamma[A]}{\delta A_{\mu_{1}}(x_{1})...\delta A_{\mu_{n}}(x_{n})}\bigg|_{A = 0}
$$
is called **the $n$-point vertex**. One would expect that in our case all of these vertices respect the gauge current conservation law $(1)$; really, typically this is true. However, there is one vertex which doesn't. This vertex is
$$
\Gamma^{\mu\nu\alpha}(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{3!}\frac{\delta^{3} \Gamma[A]}{\delta A_{\mu}(x)\delta A_{\nu}(y)\delta A_{\alpha}(z)}\bigg|_{A = 0}
$$

Comment: @CAF : It is given by the triangle diagram $AAA$. The reason is that corresponding loop integration diverges linearly in the momentum space, and corresponding divergence can't be eliminated by introducing local counter-terms (i.e., the counter-terms being linear in derivatives). In momentum space this vertex is proportional to the pole! Precisely,
$$
\tag 3 \Gamma^{\mu\nu\alpha}(p, q, k = p+q) = \frac{1}{24\pi^{2}}\frac{p^{\mu}}{p^{2}}\epsilon^{\nu\alpha\beta\gamma}p_{\beta}q_{\gamma} + \text{bose-symmetric permutations}
$$

Comment: @CAF : The conservation law for the axial gauge current now is broken: by using $(3)$ You can obtain
$$
\tag 4 \langle \partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}_{5}(x)\rangle_{A} = \frac{1}{3!}\partial_{\mu}\int d^{4}yd^{4}z\frac{\delta^{3} \Gamma[A]}{\delta A_{\mu}(x)\delta A_{\nu}(y)\delta A_{\alpha}(z)}\bigg|_{A = 0}A_{\nu}(y)A_{\alpha}(z) = \frac{1}{96\pi^{2}}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}F_{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha \beta},
$$
where $F_{\mu\nu}$ is the gauge field strength. Eq. $(4)$ is called the **gauge anomaly**.

Comment: @CAF : The gauge current now is not conserved; it turns out that this violates the unitarity and (or) the Lorentz invariance of the theory. The most top diagram of my question (the diagram A, as You've called it) just shows explicitly that the gauge anomaly violates the optical theorem.