# Contributions to final states in the optical theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, perturbation-theory, regularization, scattering-cross-section

Consider the use of the optical theorem for computing the imaginary part of the total forward scattering amplitude $\mathcal M(AB \rightarrow AB)$. Then the theorem tells us to compute 
$$2 \text{Im} \mathcal M(AB \rightarrow AB) = \sum_X \int \text{d}\Pi_X (2\pi)^4 \delta^4( p_X - p_A) |\mathcal M(AB \rightarrow X)|^2.$$ This equality holds at each order in perturbation theory, so that we can write $\mathcal M(AB \rightarrow AB) = \mathcal M^{(0)}(AB \rightarrow AB) + \alpha\mathcal M^{(1)}(AB \rightarrow AB) + \mathcal O(\alpha^2)$ in some coupling $\alpha$ and then the imaginary part of $\mathcal M^{(1)}(AB \rightarrow AB)$, say, (the sum of the first order in $\alpha$ corrections to the born level $\mathcal M^{(0)}(AB \rightarrow AB)$) is given by decorating the born level $AB \rightarrow AB$ scattering with all possible allowed virtual first order corrections.

The diagrams one needs to evaluate on the right hand side then amount to just placing final state cuts on the diagrams we having contributing to $\mathcal M^{(1)}(AB \rightarrow AB)$ on the left hand side. I think that is correct and if so, what sort of corrections do we have to consider on the left hand side for the optical theorem to hold? Do we, for example, consider self energy corrections to both the external legs and internal legs if the latter so exist at born level? I know the former are removed in a consistent procedure of dimensional regularisation and renormalisation but must they be considered for the optical theorem to hold? Must the diagrams be $\text{1PI}$, or can include tadpoles/snails? etc

Comment: Maybe, this question, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/303190/ (not answered at the moment unfortunately), will be interested for You.

Comment: Thanks!  So basically we are asking the same question if I understand correctly?  Since if one particle irreducible diagrams are only to be included (for example) then the three bubble insertion on the photon propagator you asked about should not be present on the left hand side at sixth order?

Comment: yes, my question is essentially about this, it is just more special than Your.